# What is the best approach or alternative to constant references?

Tags: c#, const-correctness, compile-time-constant

For the purposes of this question, a 'constant reference' is a reference to an object from which you cannot call methods that modify the object or modify it's properties.

I want something like this:

```
Const<User> user = provider.GetUser(); // Gets a constant reference to an "User" object
var name = user.GetName(); // Ok. Doesn't modify the object
user.SetName("New value"); // <- Error. Shouldn't be able to modify the object
```

Ideally, I would mark with a custom attribute (e.g. `[Constant]`) every method of a class that doesn't modify the instance, and only those methods can be called from the constant reference. Calls to other methods would result in an error, if possible, during compile time.

The idea is I can return a read-only reference to and be sure that it will not be modified by the client.

Comment: This is called "`const`- correctness" which is a language feature of C++ and Swift, but not C#, unfortunately - however you're onto something by using a custom attribute because that way you can enforce it via a Roslyn extension - but that's a rabbit-hole.

Comment: It is actually an immutable.

Comment: If you make all properties virtual, you can emit proxies while inheriting from the same object. In this case you can in fact do `User u = prov.GetUser(); // gets proxy`

Comment: @T.S. overridden `virtual` properties cannot remove property setters which means you won't get a compiler warning, even if the overridden setter throws `NotSupportedException`.

Comment: @Dai That is correct. Can't be removed. But OP said: *"Calls to other methods would result in an error, **if possible**, during compile time."* So, my suggestion is valid. I like it because it is not "way too complex", to emit proxy from the class it inherits

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The technique you're referring to is called ["`const`-correctness"](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/const-correctness) which is a language feature of C++ and Swift, but not C#, unfortunately - however you're onto something by using a custom attribute because that way you can enforce it via a Roslyn extension - but that's a rabbit-hole.

Alternatively, there's a much simpler solution using interfaces: because C# (and I think the CLR too) does not support const-correctness (the closest we have is the `readonly` field modifier) the .NET base-class-library designers added "read-only interfaces" to common mutable types to allow a object (wheather mutable or immutable) to expose its functionality via an interface that only exposes immutable operations. Some examples include `IReadOnlyList<T>`, `IReadOnlyCollection<T>`, `IReadOnlyDictionary<T>` - while these are all enumerable types the technique is good for singular objects too.

This design has the advantage of working in any language that supports interfaces but not const-correctness.

1. For each type (`class`, `struct`, etc) in your project that needs to expose data without risk of being changed - or any immutable operations then create an immutable interface.
2. Modify your consuming code to use these interfaces instead of the concrete type.

Like so:

Supposing we have a mutable class `User` and a consuming service:

```
public class User
{
    public String UserName     { get; set; }

    public Byte[] PasswordHash { get; set; }
    public Byte[] PasswordSalt { get; set; }

    public Boolean ValidatePassword(String inputPassword)
    {
        Hash[] inputHash = Crypto.GetHash( inputPassword, this.PasswordSalt );
        return Crypto.CompareHashes( this.PasswordHash, inputHash );
    }

    public void ResetSalt()
    {
        this.PasswordSalt = Crypto.GetRandomBytes( 16 );
    }
}

public static void DoReadOnlyStuffWithUser( User user )
{
    ...
}

public static void WriteStuffToUser( User user )
{
    ...
}
```

Then make an immutable interface:

```
public interface IReadOnlyUser
{
    // Note that the interfaces' properties lack setters.
    String              UserName     { get; }
    IReadOnlyList<Byte> PasswordHash { get; }
    IReadOnlyList<Byte> PasswordSalt { get; }

    // ValidatePassword does not mutate state so it's exposed
    Boolean ValidatePassword(String inputPassword);

    // But ResetSalt is not exposed because it mutates instance state
}
```

Then modify your `User` class and consumers:

```
public class User : IReadOnlyUser
{
    // (same as before, except need to expose IReadOnlyList<Byte> versions of array properties:
    IReadOnlyList<Byte> IReadOnlyUser.PasswordHash => this.PasswordHash;
    IReadOnlyList<Byte> IReadOnlyUser.PasswordSalt => this.PasswordSalt;
}

public static void DoReadOnlyStuffWithUser( IReadOnlyUser user )
{
    ...
}

// This method still uses `User` instead of `IReadOnlyUser` because it mutates the instance.
public static void WriteStuffToUser( User user )
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Side note: interfaces alone will not protect from un-friendly caller as they can use reflection/cast/`dynamic` to call `SetXxxx` methods of the implementing class. If this is the case you need both - interfaces and proxy implementation that hides the actual class.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov That's no-different to using `const_cast` in C++ though. I don't think it's worth developing countermeasures to adversarial library consumers anyway, as this is about eliminating potential bugs, not security.

Comment: Indeed in case of friendly client interfaces are enough. It is unclear how much protection OP is looking for "be sure that it will not be modified by the client" can be read in many different ways.

Comment: @Alexei Levenkov My intent with this is as Dai said, more related to preventing potential bugs than security. Sorry for not being entirely clear. Good observation nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

So, these are the first two ideas I initially had, but don't quite solve the problem.

Using Dynamic Objects:

The first idea I had was creating a `Dynamic Object` that would intercept all member invokations and throw an error if the method being called isn't marked with a `[Constant]` custom attribute. This approach is problematic because a) We don't have the support of the compiler to check for errors in the code (i.e. method name typos) when dealing with dynamic objects, which might lead to a lot of runtime errors; and b) I intend to use this a lot, and searching for method names by name every time a method is called might have considerable performance impact.

Using RealProxy:

My second idea was using a `RealProxy` to wrap the real object and validate the methods being called, but this only works with objects that inherit from `MarshalByRefObject`.